# Increase log verbosity on iPad console

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, logging, ios6

I'm looking for a way to increase log verbosity on iPad devices.
Right now I have several of them running exact same copy of one application. Some of the devices report complete, verbose log (Notice, Debug included), while others report only Warnings and above.

I have the same set of development certificates installed and devices expose same content (so, some give limited while others give full) of logs in both XCode and Iphone Configuration Utility.

Thanks bunches for all your help!

Comment: It seems that the verbosity is higher on IOS6 devices. All IOS5 devices seem to expose full log...

Comment: OK forget it, I just figured they disabled mirroring of stdout/stderr to /dev/console.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use `<asl.h>`. More details [here](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-1-nslogdebug-ios.html).